# Нет перевода строк в фильтрах

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, список-вопросов

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда уже заранее будут добавляться слова для перевода, хотя бы за неделю до выкатки апдейта, чтобы можно было перевести?

Comment: И официального релиза на руМете что-то я не видел. Только хотел задать вопрос, но высветился ваш.

Comment: На какой странице эти фильтры вообще? Не могу найти

Comment: @АндрейNOP в списке вопросов.

Comment: @AntonSorokin да у нас вообще объявления не делаются никогда. Я по мере возможностей иногда что-то пишу только.

Comment: Никаких новых кнопок у себя не наблюдаю: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZf2i.png // cc: @АндрейNOP

Comment: @Arhad вероятно, потому что вы на участвуете в opt: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/260198

Comment: А, ну так эту настройку почему-то запихнули в профиль на Метамете, а я смотрел на Ru.SO. Что весьма странно, ведь параметры применяются только к тому сайту, в чьём профиле были изменены. А тут нате, глобальный параметр на локальном сайте сети SE.

Comment: @Arhad не только на MSE, на SOen тоже есть эта настройка.

Comment: Долго втуплял почему у нас конкурсов нет в фильтрах, а на MSE есть. Потому что кто-то ссылку на мету сделал :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я сделять.

Comment: Очень сырая тема эти фильтры, уже устал баги им публиковать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а они этому только рады. Столько сэкономили на тестерах (¬‿¬)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переводы добавил, может быть, конечно, что-то упустил. Строк достаточно много, но они не очень сложные. Попутно выловил несколько багов для MSE :)

Короче говоря, ждём подкачки и пересборки сайта чтобы увидеть новые переводы.

На текущий момент выглядит так:

> [image: пользовательский фильтр]

Как обычно, если что не так - милости прошу в https://ru.traducir.win. Им я тоже немного ишуй накидал на гитхаб.